# Connect geth on different machines

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, genesis

I am running a private node on my machine using geth. Everything is perfect.

Even my friend is doing the same on his machine.

Is there any way in which I can connect the node on my machine with my friend's such that the transactions on my machine can be visible to him too.

I am sure it involves something to do with the genesis file, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your machine and your friend's machine can connect. then your friend should use the same genesis.json as yours.
after that, `geth console` with normal arguments, but the same networkid that you set when you create your node.

if your friend has created the node successfuly, use `admin.nodeInfo.enode` to get the enode on his machine. after taking place the `[::]` with your ip, you can use `admin.addpeer(<here is the correct enode>)` on your machine.

i think it will be ok.(and i am sorry, my english is not very well. i hope you can understand above)